How to authenticate on msgraph.GraphServiceClient?
There is no documentation for do this, I found it unacceptable.
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient

client_id = ''
client_secret = ''
tenant_id = ''
authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'
scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']

app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=client_secret,
)

response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes)

graph_client = GraphServiceClient(
    credentials=response,
    scopes=scopes
)


await graph_client.users.get()

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/kiota_authentication_azure/azure_identity_access_token_provider.py in get_authorization_token(self, uri, additional_authentication_context)
    101                 )
    102             else:
--> 103                 result = self._credentials.get_token(*self._scopes, claims=decoded_claim)
    104 
    105             if inspect.isawaitable(result):
> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'get_token'

Analyzing the stack, you can see that the object passed as credentials in the `msgraph` client is not what it expects; `acquire_token_for_client` returns a dictionary, but `GraphServiceClient` expects it to have a function called "get_token."

How can this be resolved?

Can you post the complete traceback

What I have posted is suffice, I can not share more.

Could you confirm whether your requirement is to fetch users like this https://i.imgur.com/EIusoRd.png?

The output does not matter, I simple can not use any resource in the API because the authorization.

You may refer this docs(especially ClientSecretCredential) to understand how to use it with GraphServiceClient 

I registered one Entra ID application and granted User.Read.All permission of Application type as below:

Initially, I too got same error when I ran your code to fetch list of users like this:
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient

client_id = ''
client_secret = ''
tenant_id = ''
authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'
scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']

app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=client_secret,
)

response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes)

graph_client = GraphServiceClient(
    credentials=response,
    scopes=scopes
)


result = await graph_client.users.get()
print(result)

Response:

To resolve the error, make use of below modified code that uses client credentials flow to authenticate with MS Graph and listed users successfully:
import asyncio
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient

tenant_id = "tenantID"
client_id = "appID"
client_secret = "secret"

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret
)

client = GraphServiceClient(credential)

async def main():
    result = await client.users.get()
    users = result.value

    for user in users:
        print("User ID:", user.id)
        print("User Display Name:", user.display_name)
        print("-" * 50)  # Separating each user with a line

asyncio.run(main())

Response:

References:
List users - Microsoft Graph 
GitHub - microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python
